# Fill DropDownList inside Gridview with corresponding items using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

```
protected void GridViewTicketHistory_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {
        DropDownList drpnop = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");

        if (drpnop != null)
        {
            foreach (Ticket ticket in entities.Tickets) 
            {
                foreach (State state in entities.States)
                {
                    if (ticket.StateID == state.StateID)
                    {
                        drpnop.DataTextField = state.StateName;
                        drpnop.DataValueField = state.StateID.ToString();
                    }
                }  
            }

            drpnop.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

**DataBind**

```
protected void editCustomerTicket()
{
    GridViewTicketHistory.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;

    DataTable dat = new DataTable();
    int ticketno = Convert.ToInt32(Session["TicketNo"]);

    var a = from employee in entities.Employees
            from ticket in employee.EmployeeTicket
            select new 
            {
                employee.ID,
                employee.Name,
                ticket.TicketNo,
                ticket.Subject,
                ticket.Date,
                ticket.State.StateName
            };

    GridViewTicketHistory.DataSource = a;
    GridViewTicketHistory.DataBind();
}
```

> **Problem**
>
> I use entity framework I have State and Tickets tables.Tickets has navigation property to State.(tickets.StateID).In
>   this code i tried to see each drop down list with corresponding states
>   if i use Command.Writeline i can see that state.StateName and
>   state.StateID are not empty and right values.However i see empty
>   values when i fill dropdownlist.
>
> **My Goal**
>
> My main goal is to see corresponding value on
>   Dropdownlist but also be able to choose fix items from these drop
>   downlist. Let say StateID=0 StateName=Started StateID=1 StateName=%25
>   progress StateID=2 StateName=finished Each individual ticket has state
>   Id and name and want to show it in all rows according to that
>   ticket.Also choose from the fixed list that has StateID= 0,1,2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing you need to do is avoid using anonymous type when getting the data for `GridViewTicketHistory`, because you'll need to convert `e.Row.DataItem` back to a predefined type to set the selected item of the dropdownlist. I would suggest the following class

```
public class TicketHistory
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string TicketNo { get; set; }
    public string Subject { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int? StateID { get; set; }
    public string StateName { get; set; }
}
```

Change `editCustomerTicket` method as below so the type of `a` would be a `List<TicketHistory>` instead of an anonymous type.

```
protected void editCustomerTicket()
{
    GridViewTicketHistory.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;

    var a = (from employee in entities.Employees
            from ticket in employee.EmployeeTicket
            select new TicketHistory 
            {
                ID = employee.ID,
                Name = employee.Name,
                TicketNo = ticket.TicketNo,
                Subject = ticket.Subject,
                Date = ticket.Date,
                StateID = ticket.StateID,
                StateName = ticket.State.StateName
            }).ToList();

    GridViewTicketHistory.DataSource = a;
    GridViewTicketHistory.DataBind();

}
```

When binding the dropdownlist, you have to set the `DataSource` property before calling `.DataBind()` or add the `Items` element using a loop. The code below populates the dropdownlist items using a loop and sets the selected value of the dropdownlist according to the StateID of the ticket.

```
protected void GridViewTicketHistory_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DropDownList drpnop = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownList1");

        if (drpnop != null)
        {
            // populate drpnop items
            foreach (State state in entities.States)
            {
                drpnop.Items.Add(new ListItem(state.StateName, state.StateID.ToString()));
            }

            // set the selected value of drpnop according to StateID of the ticket
            TicketHistory data = (TicketHistory)e.Row.DataItem;
            if (drpnop.Items.FindByValue(data.StateID.ToString()) != null)
            {
                drpnop.Items.FindByValue(data.StateID.ToString()).Selected = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer.When adding i changed  drpnop.Items.Add(new ListItem(state.StateName, state.StateID.ToString())); because it needs LisItem.But now it says briefly;Unable to cast object of type anonymous to Ticket.I cant   Ticket data = (Ticket)e.Row.DataItem; cast it like that and there is only one type entities.States why it says anonymous type.Because 2 data in dropdownlist?

Comment: Can you add the code where you bind the data source of `GridViewTicketHistory`? Something like `GridViewTicketHistory.DataSource = ...; GridViewTicketHistory.DataBind();`

Comment: Updated yes gridview dont have just one type and anonymous is coming from var i believe..

Comment: What's the type of `employee.EmployeeTicket`? Is it `IEnumerable<EmployeeTicket>`?

Comment: Well it comes from entities.Employee,EmployeeTicket is navigation property of Employee Table..If i look entities.Employee from Get type() its System.Data.Objects.ObjectSet`1[TrackUserModel.Employee] something like that..

Comment: What's the relation between `Employee` & `Ticket` tables? Is it one Employee to many Tickets?

Comment: See the updated answer, I think it's what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanky you It worked !!! Only in TicketHistory class  public string Date { get; set; } public int? StateID { get; set; } needed for my case.I dont have reputation so cant vote up..But thanks for your help.